# unobtrusive ajax form prevent cancel button from posting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform, unobtrusive-ajax

Question: Why is cancel button posting to the controller like submit?

I have the form below loaded from a partial view. Submit works fine. The only thing I've been struggling with is why Cancel doesn't just dismiss the form. I've tried a variety of things like capturing the click event. I looked at http://jimmylarkin.net/post/2012/05/16/Broken-Validation-on-Cancel-Buttons-With-Unobtrusive-Validation-Ajax.aspx as a possible solution but I'm not sure this is the problem it's intended to address. No doubt it's some ignorance on my part. So what bonehead thing am I missing?

```
//click event loading the form. 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#editbtn').click(function () {
            var url = "/Quiz/EditQuiz?id=@id";
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('#formdiv').html(data);
                $("#formdiv").show();
            });
        });  
</script>

//form inside partial view. 
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditQuiz", "Quiz", FormMethod.Post,
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            HttpMethod = "POST",
                            UpdateTargetId = "formdiv"
                        }))
{
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div>
            <fieldset>
            .
            .              
            <input type="submit"  class = "btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
            <button  class = "cancel" >Cancel </button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curious if your cancel button is whats causing the submit by default. Try replacing your `<button class="cancel">` with an Html helper. How about `@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index")`. This is a link that has text `Cancel` and redirects to action `Index`.

Comment: Well, that does work. Of course with ActionLink it actually redirects which I don't want, so I had to do 
<a href="#" id="cancelbutton" class="btn">Cancel</a>
and then
    $("#cancelbutton").on("click", function (event) {
                $("#formdiv").hide();
            });
Seems kinda hacky. Is that really how it should be done?

Comment: Buttons can default to type="submit" if you dont specify a type. Try specifying on your button: type="button".

Comment: well crap. That seems to be more what I'm looking for. I don't think I ever put the type attribute on buttons but I'll double-check. 
I did say "No doubt it's some ignorance on my part.":) 
Thanks Elliot

Comment: Ya putting type=button on a button seems a bit redundant, I don't blame you. No problem, good luck!